What is _Layout.cshtml.css and how is it linked to the view?
In the latest ASPNET Core 8.0 I saw this file is created

Is that means this CSS is apply automatically to all pages that uses this partial view?
If that is the case can I add _layout.cshtml.js as well?
How about all other pages? Like index.cshtml.css?


What is _Layout.cshtml.css and how is it linked to the view?

The _Layout.cshtml.css file you're referring to is likely a naming convention for a CSS file associated with the layout view in an ASP.NET Core application.
In ASP.NET Core, the _Layout.cshtml file is a special partial view that typically defines the common layout structure for all pages in your application, such as the header, footer, and navigation menu.

Is that means this CSS is apply automatically to all pages that uses
this partial view?

No, it would only work on _Layout.cshtml which includes header, footer, and navigation menu. As you can see in below example:


I have two same button class as following:
<button class="btn btn-primary">Test Button</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Another Button</button>

But they are working differently, because in _Layout.cshtml page are getting styles from _Layout.cshtml.css
On the other hand, within Index page, styles are typically gets css from static files which has been referred within css file under wwwroot.


If that is the case can I add _layout.cshtml.js as well?

No, that's not the right place to write your own javascript files. Rather, you should have your own js files or you could write within wwwroot script file. Even you can write your script with the same page using @section scripts, see the example below:
@section scripts {
    <script>
         //Write your javascript here 
    </script>
}


How about all other pages? Like index.cshtml.css?

As discussed earlier, for all other pages, you could use static files within wwwroot or you could use own css file. Remember that includes a  tag that references a CSS file when adding any external css file.
Note: Please refer to this official document how bundling works.
